# How to use Dojos Build tool?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I've written some javascript in my application which are scattered around in various javascript files. Should I use the build tool to compress them or is just for new Dijits you create?

Answer (score 1):

All dojo javascript class files include your files and dojo's files can be built to compressed and aggregated files.

And you can not only build widgets files but also your plain js files, it just depends on what your app needs.

And you can build some different layers for different usage to reduce network download.

You can look at the document from here: http://docs.dojocampus.org/build/index